# SQL: How to retrieve records ordering by date and ID for with date order predominating?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with the following contents:

```
id  Event_id    Event_name  Entry_time

1   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 09:58:08
2   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 09:58:08
3   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 09:58:37
4   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 09:58:37
5   NULL        NULL        2015-01-03 09:58:58
6   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 10:00:32
7   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 10:00:32
8   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 10:01:40
9   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 10:01:40
10  2           Cricket     2015-01-04 10:03:40
11  1           Drama Club  2015-01-04 10:01:40
```

I need to retrieve records from the table ordering by date and event_id, with the date order predominating, eg. today's records first, yesterday's records second and so on.

When I execute the query below, the records appear in wrong order as per my requirement. I need to display `Drama Club` record first because I created last entry in `Drama club`. If any one has an idea where I am going wrong, please help me.

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `event_info` 
ORDER BY DATE( Entry_time ) DESC , Event_id DESC , Event_id DESC
```

(wrong-ordered) result:

```
id  Event_id    Event_name  Entry_time

1   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 09:58:08
2   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 09:58:08
6   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 10:00:32
7   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 10:00:32
3   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 09:58:37
4   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 09:58:37
8   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 10:01:40
9   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 10:01:40
5   NULL        NULL    2015-01-03 09:58:58
```

I need below output.

```
id  Event_id    Event_name  Entry_time   
10  2           Cricket     2015-01-04 10:03:40
11  1           Drama Club  2015-01-04 10:01:40 //4th  jan section

3   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 09:58:37    
4   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 09:58:37    
8   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 10:01:40    
9   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 10:01:40    
1   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 09:58:08    
2   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 09:58:08
6   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 10:00:32    
7   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 10:00:32    
5   NULL        NULL        2015-01-03 09:58:58 //3rd jan section
```

Comment: I think that the query was mistakenly omitted, could you update your answer and provide it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED #2015-01-05 / 1**

I think that now I understood the concept - please give the following a try:

```
SELECT 
    A.* 
FROM  
    `event_info` AS A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            Event_id,
            DATE(Entry_time) AS _Event_Date,
            MAX(TIME(Entry_time)) AS Event_Max_Entry_Time
        FROM  
            `event_info`
        GROUP BY 
            Event_id, DATE(Entry_time)
    ) AS B
      ON A.Event_id = B.Event_id
          AND DATE(A.Entry_time) = B._Event_Date  
ORDER BY 
    DATE(A.Entry_time) DESC, 
    B.Event_Max_Entry_Time DESC, 
    A.Event_id DESC, 
    A.Entry_time ASC, 
    A.Event_id DESC
```

The above query gave me the exact new expected set:

```
ID  EVENT_ID    EVENT_NAME  ENTRY_TIME

10  2           Cricket     2015-01-04 10:03:40
11  1           Drama Club  2015-01-04 10:01:40 
3   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 09:58:37
4   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 09:58:37
8   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 10:01:40
9   1           Drama Club  2015-01-03 10:01:40
2   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 09:58:08
1   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 09:58:08
7   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 10:00:32
6   2           Cricket     2015-01-03 10:00:32
5   NULL        NULL        2015-01-03 09:58:58
```

Comment: I need to provide event order day wise, so my first field is ok `ORDER BY date(Entry_time) DESC`

Comment: Could you provide the expected result in your question, basing on your example?

Comment: I need output day wise, sorry i forgot to add entry other day as well, but i describe in details.

Comment: I've manage tp update the answer- now it's sorted by DATE(Entry_time) first. Please verify if you might whether now it fits. Thx in advance for reply.

Comment: thanks for reply, in your query record not showing in date wise as well as `Drama Club` showing last. i need to show at first because i made entry last with this event.

Comment: thanks for your reply, now event showing as per entry time, but here one condition remaining for showing event particular date wise, can you please one entry `Cricket` with today's date & then it not showing date wise set of the particular event.

Comment: i just updated my output with 4th January entry, can you please review it. thanks in advanced.

Comment: Hi. I'm sorry - I think I finally understood the concept - please try the updated query - it worked for me  and I hope it fits.

Comment: Thank you very much for your stuff, Is there any way to fetch same record with a single query without join?

Comment: Thanks also for your patience. For this case I can't figure out no-join solution since join is used here for applying this date- wise sort criteria. Records in table are distinguished by id and to sort them group-like like it is in this case we have to prepare group sorting criteria - this is performed in the sub query joined to the source table. If you had any doubts about the explanation please write - I'll try to make myself clearer. Regards.